# Profile Field Modification In Yii-User Module

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have installed yii-user and want to work with profile fields. I usually retrieve fields that I need as below:

```
Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user()->profile->firstname
```

But the question is how to change profiles table fields like firstname, lastname, etc from another controller?

Yii-user module itself has created **profiles** table.

Comment: maybe
$user = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user();
$user->firstname = 1;
$user->save();

Comment: @Konstantin, it doesn't work as you don't have access to profile field through $user. It gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of hassle and digging into the code I've finally managed it.
What I actually needed was to load profile model with `Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user()->profile`, and then used `setAttributes` to set profile fields values. Last but not least used `save()` to save my changes.

```
            $profileModel = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user()->profile;
            $profileModel->setAttributes(array('balance'=>1200));
            $profileModel->save();
```

It may help others. ;-)
cheers!